# IIS 7 - After deploying web project, some css and js files gives 403 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have made a web project in asp.net mvc 5 using .net framework 4.5. Unfortunately, after deploying it on IIS 7, some css and js files gives 403 error. I have already give full rights to all folders but error still remains. I face this issue first time in my life. It's really embarrassing. For reference, I have attached screen shot. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: it seems jquery file is not loaded. can you check the "page source" of your web page and see which files are getting loaded and which are failing to load!

Comment: @Nirman when i run my project via visual studio, everything works perfect but unfortunately this issue arises after deployment. I have already checked in BundleConfig.cs  that jQuery reference is there.

Comment: Make sure that your jQuery is being loaded before any of your javascript. And you should add some kind of code snippet of what your page looks like so we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by copying all the files from theme folder to css and js folder under content folder in asp.net project (default folder hierarchy). But this happens first time, before that I can refer js and css files from any folder without any problem. According to error, there is issue while accessing js and css files. But now my problem is resolved. Thanks